# Adding a field using `BundleFieldDefinition`, within an Entity Trait

Tags: 8, commerce

I've gotten to a point where I'm having trouble connecting the dots with D8.  As a result, I'm not sure I'm even asking the right question.

At this moment, I'm trying to figure out how to add a field to a class that implements `EntityTraitInterface`.

As an example, [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) provides an Entity Trait for the `commerce_product_variation` entity type.

If the trait is enabled, a field (`license_type`) is added to the product variation form - this is done within [PurchasableEntityLicensed.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_license/tree/src/Plugin/Commerce/EntityTrait/PurchasableEntityLicensed.php?h=8.x-2.x).  I want to add an additional field to that, something like:

```
$fields['license_duration'] = BundleFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
  ->setLabel(t('License Duration'))
  ->setCardinality(1)
  ->setRequired(FALSE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'boolean_checkbox',
    'weight' => 21,
  ]);
```

If I do that, and add the field to the form (in [LicenseCreateForm](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_license/tree/src/Form/LicenseCreateForm.php?h=8.x-2.x#n195)), check the box on the variation for License Duration I get the following error when trying to save the variation:

`Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\commerce_license\Plugin\Commerce\LicenseType\Base::validateConfigurationForm() must be of the type array, null given`

I'm not sure if I don't understand plugins well enough, or specifically, field plugins, or maybe Commerce.  I don't know what I don't know.

So, to be specific: how am I supposed to add this field so that it works?

Comment: This is Commerce specific, core doesn't use an entity trait. I've added this tag.